# How to get li value using url arguments in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Let us consider my URL as :  http://test/assignment/reports/55

And below is the div structure:

```
<ul class="custom-list">
<li value="55">testT</li>
<li value="58">testt</li>
<li value="60">123333333333</li>
</ul>
```

**By using the argument -> 55 i need to alert the name in the browser using jquery.**

For example when i load the above url:

**I need to alert the value as testT and class name as "custom-list".**

How can i do this using jquery?

Comment: There are no `div` nodes in your "div structure"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curr = location.href.match(/\d+$/);
    if(curr){
        curr = curr[0];
        var elem = $("li[value='" + curr + "']");
        if(elem.length) alert(elem.text());
    }
});
```

Use a RegExp to get last digits of your URL (`\d+$`). If the element exists, alert the text content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastSegmentOfUrl = window.location.pathname.slice(window.location.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var theElementWithTheValueOfTheLastSegment = $('[value="' + lastSegmentOfUrl + '"]');
```

Will give you the basics of what you want to do:

```
alert(theElementWithTheValueOfTheLastSegment.text());
```

You can check whether the contents of the last segment matches an element, by checking the `.length` property of the jQuery object:

```
if (theElementWithTheValueOfTheLastSegment.length) {
    // > 1 element matched
} else {
    // no elements matched
}
```

For more info, see the [`window.location` object on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this jQuery-URL-Parser plugin:

https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Then it would be a matter of:

```
var myVal = url.segment(3);
var toAlert = $('li[value='+myVal+']').html();
alert(toAlert);
```